# Difference in meaning between "use", "employ" and "utilize"

Tags: word-usage, register

I am confused with the words "use", "employ" and "utilize".

What is the difference in their meanings, and where they are supposed to be used?
There is another topic with the same question, but it is poorly explained.

Could it be used in the title of articles as in the examples below?

> Utilizing the advantages of Google mail.
>
> Employing external phone numbers in corporate phone system.

Comment: If there is another question that hasn't attracted answers, don't repost it. Rather, edit it to get more attention for it or add a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Utilizing an advantage" is may be grammatical but it is not idiomatic, and I have no idea what it would mean to "employ a phone number".   That which is used, employed, or utilized should be a tool, implement, device, or instrument of some kind, something which can be *wielded*, literally or figuratively.

> Let's use this key to see if it works.
>
> We can use her to get to him.

We can *make (good) use* of Google mail because of its various features. We can *put them to use*. We can take advantage of those features.  We can use Google Mail to good advantage.

It's grammatical, but we cannot  employ or utilize advantages, not without sounding a little vacant:

> We can utilize our advantage to our advantage.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the words? And why cannot we use or employ phone numbers?

Comment: The question is too broad.  They have different meanings in different contexts. My advice: avoid **utilize** altogether.  **use** will always work there.   With respect to **employ**, if you're speaking of a person/hireling, use **employ**.  If you're speaking of the person as if they were a tool, use **use**.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, reveal your reasoning.  Your anonymity is tiresome and cowardly.